# How can I concatenate a map structure to visualize it?

Tags: php, html

I am developing a game with maps (named channels) which are connected via warps. Each channel has an ID (int) and each warp has a channel source ID (int) and a channel target ID (int). A channel can have an infinite number of warps or no warps at all.

I built an administration app (with Zend Expressive / php and HTML) which gets the channel data from an API as JSON. This JSON is then parsed to simplified classes which include only the important data.

I tried to visualize the data in kind of a grid, to determine the border of the world.

I tried to visualize it with divs, with fixed size and ordering. Unfortunately I have no idea how to handle the variable number of neighbours. There are coordinates available where the warps are placed, but I want a more abstract view of the world. I just want every channel to be represented by a fixed size 2D cube (div with fixed width and height).

Channel class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Channel
{
    protected $id;
    protected $neighbourIds = [];

    public function parseData(array $data)
    {
        $this->setId($data['id']);
        foreach($data['warps'] as $warp) {
            $this->addNeighbourId($warp['targetChannelId']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function addNeighbourId($neighbourId)
    {
        $this->neighbourIds[] = $neighbourId;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNeighbourIds()
    {
        return $this->neighbourIds;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $neighbours
     */
    public function setNeighbours($neighbours): void
    {
        $this->neighbours = $neighbours;
    }
}
```

Sample data in channels as print_r output

```php
Array
(
    [0] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 1
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 121
                )

        )

    [1] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 4
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 5
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 2
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 133
                    [3] => 138
                    [4] => 152
                    [5] => 175
                    [6] => 176
                )

        )

    [4] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 3
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 126
                    [2] => 132
                    [3] => 137
                )

        )

    [5] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 121
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 122
                    [2] => 139
                    [3] => 144
                )

        )

    [6] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 122
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 121
                    [1] => 123
                    [2] => 140
                    [3] => 145
                )

        )

    [7] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 123
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 122
                    [1] => 124
                    [2] => 141
                    [3] => 146
                )

        )

    [8] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 124
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123
                    [1] => 125
                    [2] => 142
                    [3] => 147
                )

        )

    [9] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 125
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 124
                    [1] => 143
                    [2] => 148
                )

        )

    [10] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 126
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 127
                    [2] => 131
                    [3] => 136
                )

        )

    [11] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 127
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 126
                    [1] => 128
                    [2] => 130
                    [3] => 135
                )

        )

    [12] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 128
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 127
                    [1] => 129
                    [2] => 134
                )

        )

    [13] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 129
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 130
                    [1] => 128
                )

        )

    [14] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 130
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 129
                    [1] => 131
                    [2] => 127
                )

        )

    [15] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 131
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 130
                    [1] => 132
                    [2] => 126
                )

        )

    [16] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 132
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 131
                    [1] => 133
                    [2] => 3
                )

        )

    [17] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 133
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 132
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [18] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 134
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 135
                    [1] => 128
                )

        )

    [19] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 135
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 134
                    [1] => 136
                    [2] => 127
                )

        )

    [20] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 136
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 135
                    [1] => 137
                    [2] => 126
                )

        )

    [21] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 137
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 136
                    [1] => 138
                    [2] => 3
                )

        )

    [22] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 138
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 137
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [23] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 139
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 140
                    [1] => 121
                )

        )

    [24] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 140
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 139
                    [1] => 141
                    [2] => 122
                )

        )

    [25] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 141
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 140
                    [1] => 142
                    [2] => 123
                )

        )

    [26] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 142
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 141
                    [1] => 143
                    [2] => 124
                )

        )

    [27] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 143
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 142
                    [1] => 125
                )

        )

    [28] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 144
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 145
                    [1] => 121
                )

        )

    [29] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 145
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 144
                    [1] => 146
                    [2] => 122
                )

        )

    [30] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 146
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 145
                    [1] => 147
                    [2] => 123
                )

        )

    [31] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 147
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 146
                    [1] => 148
                    [2] => 124
                )

        )

    [32] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 148
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 147
                    [1] => 125
                )

        )

    [33] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 152
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

    [34] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 175
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

    [35] => App\Entity\Channel Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 176
            [neighbourIds:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

I expect kind of a grid to visualize the channels in relation, to enable administration of the data (delete, extend, etc.). My question only refers to the visualization part.